# AngularJS: How to tell if a form has focus?

Tags: angularjs

Angular has ng-focus to attach to a form-field to tell if it has focus.

But as I understand I cannot use `ng-focus` on the `<form>` itself. What would be the simplest way to tell if any field in a form has focus but without attaching ng-focus on each and every field? Say I have a large form with many fields, and I do want check each field...

Comment: you should consider rephrase your question because I don't think it is possible to understand what you need. it seems that you request an ng-focus , but you state that on your question.

Comment: ng-focus is for form field only, right? I am looking for the form in general (if any field has focus). I can try to clarify in the question...

Comment: Got it, but why would you want to do that ? if you need events only from specific fields just set a ng-focus for these fields ? you can set them to call the same function when called and by looking at the event you can decide what do you want to do.

Comment: @EricC I don't think it is possible to use the ngFocus (it only works on inputs) in the way you are wanting. However you might be able to write a directive that could capture if in part the form is currently focused.

Comment: @Nuno_147, to avoid putting ng-focus on all of my many fields where I really do not need it. I guess semantically it is also logically, I do not want to handle focus on a specific field, I want to handle focus on the form in general...

Comment: @JaredReeves, that makes sense :) Perhaps put that in answer form and I could accept that?